# documentImport set to accept only zip, but allows doc/docx as well - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular9

I'm working in an Angular 9 project.
We have a component that takes a file from the user. We're using the documentImport input for this:

```
<button
  *ngIf="showButton"
  (click)="documentImport.value = null; documentImport.click()"
  class="newDocument-button mat-elevation-z4 float-right"
  mat-raised-button
  color="primary">
       {{ importText }}
</button>
<input
  #documentImport
  type="file"
  id="documentUpload"
  name="documentUpload"
  (change)="onDocumentSelected($event)"
  accept="{{ acceptedFormats }}"
  style="display:none;"
/>
```

You see that I have `accept` set to a var. That var is: `acceptedFormats = [".zip"];`
So I would think that only zip files would be allowed. However, it allow for zip and for doc and docx files.
I need to limit the select to only allow zips, no doc/docx.

From the documentation on the documentImport, the above should work, any ideas on how to resolve this?
Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: According to MDN accept parameter should be a string, not an array, try to provide ".zip" instead of [".zip"], if you want to keep accepted formats as an array, try to converting it to string before passing to input.

Comment: @MichałTkaczyk Thanks you, but changing it to not be an array (so that's it's just `.zip`) doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: It doesn't because it doesn't work or because you want to use array? If you want to use array, you can covert your array to string before passing it to input, i.e. if you have array like this: `['.zip', '.jpg']` you can convert it to string by using `.join(',')` on that array.

Comment: @MichałTkaczyk It didn't work because I used: `acceptedFormats = ".zip";` and was still able to select docx/doc file along with zip files.